# Cross-thread operation not valid error when i get string from other Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

At my code, I design a GUI that managed in one task .
From the Form1 class I send parameters to method to other class at different task and get parameters from the task.

At form1 class I have `myEvt_valueChnaged(string s)` method that gets string `s` as argument - string that contain the text of textbox that send from the event at manager class - invoked from different task.

With the received string I update the textbox at the GUI as wrote here:

```
private void myEvt_valueChnaged(string s)
{
    textBox1.Text = s;
}
```

with this code I get the error:

```
invalidoperationexception was unhandled by user code - Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

I tried to add line at the method : `var y =s; and then textBox1.Text=y;` but it didn't solve it.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

A UI element may only be changed by the UI thread. You need to Invoke the action instead:

```
private void myEvt_valueChnaged(string s)
{
    textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = s));
}
```